# How to replace an empty InfluxDB query result with a single value for the single stat visualization

Tags: influxql, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I'm using the new InfluxDB2 and the flux query language to retrieve docker stats from my bucket. I want to display the uptime of a container in a single stat widget.

For this I use the following query:

```
   from(bucket: "docker")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "docker_container_status")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "uptime_ns")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r.container_name == "some_container")
  |> window(period: v.windowPeriod)
  |> last()
```

Unfortunately, the container wasn't online in the past time range, therefore I get a "No results" displayed. Instead I would like to display a 0 value or a text like "Not online".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, when there is no data, it should use 0.0 to fill

```
   from(bucket: "docker")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "docker_container_status")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "uptime_ns")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r.container_name == "some_container")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: (tables=<-, column="_value") => 
tables |> last(column) |> sum(column))
  |> fill(value: 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Grafana you can use the option for "No value" to select what you want displayed if there are no results / No Data from your query.